# Adding new rows in table not displaying related information from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a table where you can add and remove rows. I have a select option where you select a customer and then it populates a dropdown in the table with all the products. Once you have selected a product, it populates all the fields correlating that product, such as: price, description, tax etc.

My issue is that when i add a new row to the table, the products display in the new dropdown, however when i select a product it does not display the information for that product in the new row fields.

**Table**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
     <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th><h6>Item</h6></th>
     <th><h6>Description</h6></th>
     <th><h6>Rate</h6></span></th>
     <th><h6>Quantity</h6></th>
     <th><h6>Tax</h6></th>
     <th><h6>Subtotal</h6></th>
     </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody id="orders">
     <tr>
     <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success circle">Add row</button></td>
     <!------ Item -------->
     <td><select style="width: 100%;" name="item" id="item1" class="browser-default custom-select-new"> 
         <option value="" disabled selected>Click to See Products</option>

                          <?php
                          $records = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM customer_product WHERE customer LIKE '$Comid' ");
                          while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
                          $price = $data['new_total_rate'];
                            $product = $data['product'];
                            $discription = $data['description'];

                             echo '<option value="' . $data['product'] . '"  
                                 data-new_price_rate="' . $data['new_total_rate'] . '" 
                                 data-description="' . $data['description'] . '" 
                                 data-tax="' . $data['tax'] . '" >'
                                . $data['product'] . '</option>';     
                          }
                          ?>
         </select>
         </td>
         <!------ Description -------->
         <td><input class="form-control description" type='text' id='description1' name='description[]' for="1"/></td>

         <!------ Rate -------->
         <td><input class="form-control product_price" type='number' data-type="product_price" id='product_price1' name='product_price[]' for="1"/></td>

         <!------ Quantity -------->
         <td><input class="form-control quantity" type='number' id='quantity_1' name='quantity[]' for="1"/></td>

         <!------ Tax -------->
         <td><input class="form-control tax" type='number' id='tax1' name='tax[]' for="1"/></td>

         <!------ SubTotal -------->
         <td><input class="form-control total_cost" type='text' id='total_cost_1' name='total_cost[]' for='1' readonly/></td>
       </tr>           
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

**Script to add new rows**

```
<script>

var rowCount = 1;
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#add').click(function() {
   rowCount++;
   $('#orders').append('<tr id="row'+rowCount+'"><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'
+rowCount+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove circle">Remove</button></td><td><select style="width: 100%;" name="item'+rowCount+'" id="item'
+rowCount+'" class="browser-default custom-select-new"><option value="" disabled selected>Click to See Products</option><?php $records = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM customer_product WHERE customer LIKE '$Comid' "); while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) { echo '<option value="' . $data['product'] . '" data-new_price_rate="' . $data['new_total_rate'] . '" data-description="' . $data['description'] . '" data-tax="' . $data['tax'] . '" >' . $data['product'] . '</option>'; } ?></select></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="description'
+rowCount+'" name="description[]" for="'+rowCount+'"/></td><td><input class="form-control" type="number" id="product_price'
+rowCount+'" name="product_price[]" for="'+rowCount+'"/></td><input class="form-control" type="hidden" data-type="product_id" id="product_id_'
+rowCount+'" name="product_id[]" for="'+rowCount+'"/><td><input class="form-control" type="number" class="quantity" id="quantity_'
+rowCount+'" name="quantity[]" for="'+rowCount+'"/> </td><td><input class="form-control" type="number" id="tax'
+rowCount+'" name="tax[]"  for="'+rowCount+'"/> </td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="total_cost_'
+rowCount+'" name="total_cost[]"  for="'+rowCount+'" readonly/> </td></tr>');
  });
});

</script>
```

**Script to get values from rows and new row values**

```
<script>
for(let i=1; i<25; i++) {
let mySelect = document.getElementById("item" + i);

if (mySelect !== null) {

mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("product_price" + i).value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-new_price_rate"))
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("description" + i).value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-description"))
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("tax" + i).value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-tax"))
console.log(mySelect);

    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: _"Script to get values from rows and new row values"_ - that code is not wrapped into a function, so presumably it executes only _once_ after the page has loaded? Then all elements you add after that, will of course not have gotten any change handlers assigned to them. The keyword you should go read up on, is _event delegation_.

Comment: @CBroe, thank you i had a look at it, and implemented it into my code, it gets the values from each new row now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
for(let i=1; i<25; i++) {

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) { 

let mySelect = document.getElementById("item" + i);

if (mySelect !== null) {

mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("product_price" + i).value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-new_price_rate"))
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("description" + i).value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-description"))
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("tax" + i).value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-tax"))

console.log(mySelect);

    }
  });  
 }
</script>
```